# How to send an email to my email address using an HTML form and PHP in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a simple form in WordPress to send an email after the submit button is clicked, however when the submit button is clicked the page refreshes and I get redirected to my 404 page.  This happens regardless of where I specify for it to redirect to, even if I say to make it redirect to the same page.  Is there anyway I can use the mail function and avoid getting the 404 error that I've been running into?  I would appreciate any help in locating this!  Thank you!

```
<form method="post">
            <h1 class="sectionHeader title">Contact</h1>
            <div id="inputContainer">
                <div class="flexChildInput" id="nameInput">
                    <h4 class="contactLabels">Name</h4>
                    <input type="text" name="name" required />
                </div>
                <div class="flexChildInput" id="emailInput">
                    <h4 class="contactLabels">Email</h4>
                    <input type="text" name="email" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="commentsContainer">
                <h4 class="contactLabels">Comments</h4>
                <textarea name="comments" id="" cols="30" style="height: 25vh;" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <input name="action" hidden />
            <div id="submitContainer">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <?php
                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

                    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST(['name'])) && !empty($_POST(['email'])) && !empty($_POST(['comments']))) {
                        $to = $_POST['myemail@email.com'];
                        $subject = $_POST['name'] + " has sent you a message!";
                        $message = $_POST['comments'];
                        $from = $_POST['email'];
                        $headers = "From:" . $from;

                        //(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

                        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                            echo "Mail Sent.";
                        } else {
                            echo "failed";
                        }
                    }

                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: the PHP code should be at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

It's so simple to achieve that. Refer the following sample code:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
         //code to be executed
    }else{
         //code to be executed  
    }
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
     <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP Script will only run if the submit button is clicked.

Comment: So this code still redirects me to a 404 page within WordPress which was more of the underlying issue.  Is there a way to make my page not redirect to something new?  I've tried to set action="#" but it will try to look for a new page regardless